# Default text on opening a new file of a certain extension(ex: .cpp)

Tags: templates, vim, atom-editor

I want some default text like:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   // code
   return 0;
}
```

to come whenever I open a `.cpp` file in Vim or Atom. I searched a lot in various forums but could not find answers except for Visual Studio but not for Vim or Atom.

Comment: You might want to read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: @Bo Persson .. Thank you for the link .... updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vim has multiple events where we can discover if a new file is created or a file is opened:

```
if has("autocmd")   
    au BufNewFile,BufRead *.cpp "Do something
endif
```

We want to check whether the file we opened is empty checks if a file has a file system location, let's put this in a function so it's easier to read:

```
function! EmptyFile()
    if (line('$') == 1 && getline(1) == '')
        "Do something
    endif
endfunction
```

The last thing we want to do is insert some template based on a existing file:

```
function! LoadTemplate(template)
    let fl = readfile(template)
    call append('', fl)
endfunction
```

Now everything together (you should add it to your `.vimrc`):

```
function! AddEmptyTemplate(template)
    if (line('$') == 1 && getline(1) == '')
        let fl = readfile(a:template)
        call append('', fl)
    endif
endfunction

if has("autocmd")   
    au BufNewFile,BufRead *.cpp call AddEmptyTemplate("cpp-template.cpp")
    au BufNewFile,BufRead *.c call AddEmptyTemplate("c-template.c")
endif
```

This assumes you have the files in folders Vim can find.

Comment: Thanks , that helped a lot.

Comment: There is one problem though i am encountering....if I put cpp-template in some folder (say home) then I am not able to access that template on opening a .cpp file in other folder unless i copy paste the same template in that folder

Comment: Try it with `BufRead,BufNewFile`.  `BufEnter` is called whenever you switch buffers, and that's definitely not what you want.

Comment: Edit : The problem was fixed by using glob command in readfile and keeping no parameter in AddEmptyTemplate() function . Although this removes versatility of function , it fixed the problem of not opening template in different folders

Answer (score 1):

That's what snippets are for.  Use a snippet plugin, such as [UltiSnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips).  You'll also need a set of snippets to start with, such as [vim-snippets](https://github.com/honza/vim-snippets).